# Is it possible to draw exiting image on iPhone map?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I am developing simple map base app.I can add `MKPolyline` using https://github.com/wlach/nvpolyline tutorial. But I want to add(draw) exiting image on iPhone map view which can be scale like `MKPolyline`.

Please Help me,
Thanks In Advance.